# Laravel Controller Check Multiple Arrays

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am sending multiple arrays via AJAX to my controller and I'm having trouble with validation.

I have 2 text inputs. Now, the issue is that at times both these inputs are present, but at other times only one might be present.

```
<input type="text" name="typeDetails[games]" class="form-control input-global"/>
<input type="text" name="typeDetails[art]" class="form-control input-global"/>
```

My JS is like this.

```
var data = { 'typeDetails[games]' : [], 'typeDetails[art]' : [] };

$("input[name='typeDetails[games]']").each(function() {
    data['typeDetails[games]'].push($(this).val());
}); 

$("input[name='typeDetails[art]']").each(function() {
    data['typeDetails[art]'].push($(this).val());
});
```

In my controller, I want to (1) make sure that there's a validation of required and (2) if the "games" array is present, perform a particular action and if the "art" array is present, perform a different action.

```
$typeDetails = Input::get('typeDetails');            

if ($request->has('typeDetails.games'))
{
    return 'games';
}

if ($request->has('typeDetails.art'))
{
    return 'art';
}
```

What happens here is that in my console it properly returns 'games', but even if the "art" array has values and is sent with the request, it doesn't return 'art'. I must be missing a fundamental understanding with php here.

Thanks!

**ANSWER**

Here's how I got it to work.

```
$typeDetails = Input::get('typeDetails');      

    $this->validate($request, [
        'typeDetails.*.*' => 'required|max:50'
    ],[
        'required' => 'You must type in some keywords to continue.',
        'max' => 'Your input must be less than 50 characters.'
    ]);

if ($request->has('typeDetails.games'))
{
    $gameInfo = Input::get('typeDetails.games');

    foreach ($gameInfo as $key => $value)
    {
        DB::table('user_type')->insert([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'type_id' => '1',
            'user_type_details' => $value,
            'created_at' => Carbon::now()
        ]);   
    }        
}

if ($request->has('typeDetails.art'))
{
    $artInfo = Input::get('typeDetails.art');

    foreach ($artInfo as $key => $value)
    {
        DB::table('user_type')->insert([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'type_id' => '2',
            'user_type_details' => $value,
            'created_at' => Carbon::now()
        ]);

    }
}
```

Comment: If you're returning in the conditional check for typeDetails.game, you will never reach the check for typeDetails.art, as the function has already returned at that point.

Comment: Ah ok. I knew it was something fundamental. Thanks for the clarification! Now, for a 'required' validation, would it work to have that validation on the overall typeDetails object or do it individually within the 'game' or 'art' checks?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but you may be able to use the dot '.' accessor in array keys for validation. That way you could validate against 'typeDetails.games' and 'typeDetails.art' in the same validator but with different rules.

Comment: I figured out how to do it. Question is updated. Thanks!

Comment: You can remove the exploit checks for request->has() as the required rule on the validator will fail if it's not present